# How To Implement "defaults()" For Multiple Params In A Route - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a `POST` URL with two parameters and I want to assign default values for both parameters .

I know you can implement this way for a URL with a single param:

```
Route::post('activity-log/datatable/{tag_access?}/{page_access?}',
'SettingsController@datatable_activity_log')
->defaults('tag_access', 'activity-log');
```

But how do i go about it with a URL that looks like this:

```
Route::post('activity-log/datatable/{tag_access?}/{page_access?}',
'SettingsController@datatable_activity_log')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see regarding the usage of defaults you can either do one at a time:

```php
Route::post('activity-log/datatable/{tag_access?}/{page_access?}',
'SettingsController@datatable_activity_log')
->defaults('tag_access', 'activity-log')
->defaults('page_access', 'defaultValue');
```

An alternative (since `defaults` is public) is to do:

```php
$route = Route::post('activity-log/datatable/{tag_access?}/{page_access?}',
'SettingsController@datatable_activity_log');
$route->defaults = [ 'tag_access' => 'activity-log', 'page_access' => 'defaultValue' ];
```

My personal favourite is what @Sagar Gautam suggest which is to use default function parameters.

Comment: Okay I prefer this solution. Default function parameters looks ugly to me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it by following way:

Keep your route as you want like this:

```
Route::post('activity-log/datatable/{tag_access?}/{page_access?}','SettingsController@datatable_activity_log')
```

Now, In controller function you can take these parameters with default value like this,

```
public function datatable_activity_log($tag_access='activity-log', $page_access='activity-log', Request $request){
    // Here write your logic
}
```

This may not be the best way to achieve what you want but this is one of the way.

Comment: thanks for answering, but i thought the defaults param would be neater. So it's not possible that way?

Comment: @IkechukwuKalu Yes, I have mentioned that this is one way but may be not the best one.